# The if statement in JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement

I have two "if" statements in my code, what can I do so that if one "if" statement is true the other is automatically ignored / disabled?

Comment: read up on "else", the part of an "if" statement that gets executed if the condition is false.

Comment: I know the problem is, there are certain conditions where both of the "if" statements can become true.. therefore I am having two if conditions doing there job at the same time... What do you think?

Comment: @Matthew You may require to use `return` before going to next `if`.

Comment: Not sure this should have been closed.  The guy is 'getting there.'

Comment: Not sure why the question got closed :p

Comment: @DrColossos Yepp thats the one: else if. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have the following:

```
if(condition1){
   block1;
}
if(condition2){
   block2;
}else{
   block3;
}
```

To disable/ignore the second `if` you can either use an `else if` statement:

```
if(condition1){
   block1;
} else if(condition2){
   block2;
}else{
   block3;
}
```

Or a return statement after `block1`

```
if(condition1){
   block1;
   return;
}
if(condition2){
   block2;
}else{
   block3;
}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the "return;" in general? I cannot understand it :S

Comment: The return basically means: **I AM DONE, DON'T BOTHER GOING ANY FURTHER** :)

Comment: This solution addresses the symptom.

Comment: @TonyEnnis I disagree. The OP's question is how to ignore the second `if` statement not about re-factoring his code

Answer (score 3):

```
    if(maxValY < 3)
    {
        p.setColor(Color.black);
        //display the value of graph width and graph height
        aw = String.valueOf(x1);
        p.drawString("Graph Width = ", 740,490);
        p.drawString(aw,840,490);
        p.drawString("Graph Height = ", 740,510);
        String ah = String.valueOf(y1);
        p.drawString(ah,846,510);
    } 
    else
    {   if (minValx == -1 || minValx == - 2 || minValx == - 3){
        p.setColor(Color.black);
        //display the value of graph width and graph height
        aw = String.valueOf(x1);
        p.drawString("Graph Width = ", 740,90);
        p.drawString(aw,840,90);
        p.drawString("Graph Height = ", 740,110);
        String ah = String.valueOf(y1);
        p.drawString(ah,846,110);
        }
        else{
        p.setColor(Color.black);
        //display the value of graph width and graph height
        aw = String.valueOf(x1);
        p.drawString("Graph Width = ", 50,90);
        p.drawString(aw,150,90);
        p.drawString("Graph Height = ", 50,110);
        String ah = String.valueOf(y1);
        p.drawString(ah,156,110);
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers, at least.  One is to put a return statement at the bottom of the 1st `if` statement.  I don't like that because it may not be a good general solution.

Another answer is to restructure your code a little...

First, since the case is where maxValX is >= 3 doesn't seem to be where the problem lies, I'd get that out of the way by reversing the first `if` conditional:

```
    if (maxValY >= 3) {
        p.setColor(Color.black);
        //display the value of graph width and graph height
        aw = String.valueOf(x1);
        p.drawString("Graph Width = ", 50, 90);
        p.drawString(aw, 150, 90);
        p.drawString("Graph Height = ", 50, 110);
        String ah = String.valueOf(y1);
        p.drawString(ah, 156, 110);
    } else if (maxValY < 3) {
        p.setColor(Color.black);
        //display the value of graph width and graph height
        aw = String.valueOf(x1);
        p.drawString("Graph Width = ", 740, 490);
        p.drawString(aw, 840, 490);
        p.drawString("Graph Height = ", 740, 510);
        String ah = String.valueOf(y1);
        p.drawString(ah, 846, 510);
    }
    if (minValx == -1 || minValx == -2 || minValx == -3) {
        p.setColor(Color.black);
        //display the value of graph width and graph height
        aw = String.valueOf(x1);
        p.drawString("Graph Width = ", 740, 90);
        p.drawString(aw, 840, 90);
        p.drawString("Graph Height = ", 740, 110);
        String ah = String.valueOf(y1);
        p.drawString(ah, 846, 110);
    }
```

So all that happened was that I put the 'non duplicate if statement issue' at the top.

Now, we have two conditions, one that deals with `minValX`, and one that deals with `maxValY`. But we now notice that the contents of each are nearly identical.  We solve this by refactoring the code a little (and sneaking in an else...):

```
    if (maxValY >= 3) {
        p.setColor(Color.black);
        //display the value of graph width and graph height
        aw = String.valueOf(x1);
        p.drawString("Graph Width = ", 50, 90);
        p.drawString(aw, 150, 90);
        p.drawString("Graph Height = ", 50, 110);
        String ah = String.valueOf(y1);
        p.drawString(ah, 156, 110);
    } else if (maxValY < 3) {
        q(491, 510);
    } else if (minValx == -1 || minValx == -2 || minValx == -3) {
        q(90, 110);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("This cannot possibly happen ;-)");
    }
}

private void q(int loc1, int loc2) {
    p.setColor(Color.black);
    //display the value of graph width and graph height
    aw = String.valueOf(x1);
    p.drawString("Graph Width = ", 740, loc1);
    p.drawString(aw, 840, loc1);
    p.drawString("Graph Height = ", 740, loc2);
    String ah = String.valueOf(y1);
    p.drawString(ah, 846, loc2);
}
```

And then we notice the code blocks are *still* nearly identical.  Refactor...

```
private void someName() {
    // ...
    if (maxValY >= 3) {
        q(50, 90, 510);
    } else if (maxValY < 3) {
        q(740, 490, 510);
    } else if (minValx == -1 || minValx == -2 || minValx == -3) {
        q(740, 90, 110);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("This cannot possibly happen ;-)");
    }
    // ...
}

private void q(int base, int graphWidth, int graphHeight) {
    p.setColor(Color.black);
    //display the value of graph width and graph height
    aw = String.valueOf(x1);
    p.drawString("Graph Width = ", base, graphWidth);
    p.drawString(aw, base+100, graphWidth);
    p.drawString("Graph Height = ", base, graphHeight);
    String ah = String.valueOf(y1);
    p.drawString(ah, base+100+6, graphHeight);
}
```

So we see that all three sections of code were basically the same except for some constants.    By refactoring them out, we reduce the amount of code that must be debugged.  In addition, we see the structure of the `if` statement clearly and have separated the logic from the actual work, which frequently yields additional dividends.

Comment: The OP's question is how to ignore the second if statement not about re-factoring his code

Comment: @GETah Yep.  And with this solution, the OP gets what he wanted, using the preferred construct, and hopefully learns a little more beyond that.  Beginners often ask the wrong question, and this was the case here.